# Condition for special equivalence relation

Tags: self-learning, equivalence-relations

I am quite stuck with the following problem:

Let $M$ be a set and $S \subseteq M^2$. Define the relation $\sim$ as

$ a \sim b :\Leftrightarrow \exists x_0, x_1, ..., x_{n-1} \in M$ with $x_0 = a$ and $x_n = b$ s.t. $\forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ it is $(x_{i-1}, x_i) \in S$ or $(x_i, x_{i-1}) \in S$. Under what conditions is this relation an equivalence relation?

Of course, I know the criteria for equivalence relations, i.e. reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity. I also tried to sketch the problem, interpreting the $x_i$ as nodes and the $(x_i, x_{i-1})$ as edges but I am not too familiar with graph theory. In short, I don't seem to grasp what has to be considered here.

Comment: I think the question needs to mention that n needs to be a natural number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have symmetry ($\forall (a,b) \in M^2, a \sim b \implies b \sim a$ by taking the reverse sequence) and reflexivity ($\forall a \in M, a \sim a$ by taking the sequence $(a)$).

Let $(a, b, c) \in M^3$ such that $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$. You need to have transitivity (ie to always have $a \sim c$).

Let $x_0, ..., x_n$ be a sequence leading from $a$ to $b$ and $x_n, ..., x_{n'}$ from $b$ to $c$. You then have $x_0, ..., x_n, ..., x_{n'}$ which is a sequence that leads from $a$ to $c$ therefore $a\sim c$

Thus your relation is always an equivalence relation

Comment: If $S$ is not symmetric then you simply cannot take the reverse sequence. You can only take sequence $(a)$ if $\langle a,a\rangle\in S$ which is not guaranteed.

Comment: @drhab Since you only need $(x_{i-1}, x_i)$ OR $(x_i, x_{i-1})$ to be in S the reverse sequence does fit, does it not ?

Comment: Yes, I see now (too late). Sorry for that.How about my objection against reflexivity?

Comment: @drhab For the sequence $(a)$, $\forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ translates as $\forall i \in \emptyset$ since $n=0$ (leading the statement to be immediatly true)

Comment: Again you are right. My downvote is now an upvote, and I deleted my wrong answer.

Comment: After all quite obvious then. The second time you helped me today. Thanks, Astyx!

Comment: It's my pleasure